# Id passed on url via link can't be processed on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a link in which I want to pass an id through the URL to process it in other model's action such as new and create.

in _response.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Reply", new_subcomment_path(:response_id => response.id), id: "new_subcomment"%>
```

when clicked, it will bring me to new view, and I can actually see the parameter I passed from _response.html.erb partial via the link above. ie: http://localhost:3000/subcomments/new?response_id=152 No problem at all.

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @subcomment do |f| %>
<%= f.input :comment_text, as: :text, input_html: {rows: 1} %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
```

Now the PROBLEM is When I click submit, I will get this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Response without an ID):
>     app/controllers/subcomments_controller.rb:10:in `create'

Here is my subcomments_controller.rb

```
def new
    @response = Response.find(params[:response_id])
    @subcomments = @response.subcomments.all
    @subcomment = @response.subcomments.new
end

def create
    @response = Response.find(params[:response_id])
    @task = @response.task
    @subcomment = @response.subcomments.new(subcomment_params)
    @subcomment.save

    redirect_to @task 

end

private
def subcomment_params
    params.require(:subcomment).permit(:comment_text)
end
```

and here is my route file:

```
resources :tasks do
  resources :responses 
end
resources :responses do
  resources :subcomments
end
resources :subcomments
```

I am really intrigued of what is wrong with the link I passed and the parameter as it seems it cant be processed in the create action.
Please help me to figure out whats wrong here >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form doesn't have anywhere for the `response_id` to go, so there's no way for it to be submitted to the create action, inside your `simple_form_for` add a line like:

```
<%= f.hidden :response_id %>
```

**But note:** by doing this the user *can* change this value, I assume this is not a problem for you and your business logic because you're already accepting `response_id` in link to your `new` action.

Answer (score 0):

Well your problem is in the first line of the `create` action: `@response = Response.find(params[:response_id])`. You are trying to find a record with params `params[:response_id]` but the above returns `nil`, hence the error `Couldn't find Response without an ID`

It's as if you are doing `Respond.find(nil)`. Inspect your params; the `respond_id` might not exist or is nested in a different fashion.